# Unable to create folder inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a folder(/data/connect) inside my docker container at location (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da) and for that, I have mentioned that step inside my dockerfile (RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect) but somehow this particular folder is not getting created inside this directly here is my dockerfile.

```
FROM python:2.7.18 as build
WORKDIR /build

COPY config/requirements.txt \
 config/test.json \
 builddir/.netrc \
 ./
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect
COPY config/config.json /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect

##############################################################
FROM python:2.7.18-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /build /app
RUN mv .netrc ~ && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get upgrade --assume-yes && \
# Used by Pipeline to differentiate from manually installed packages
apt list --installed >/tmp/preinstalled-packages 2>/dev/null  && \
apt-get clean && \
groupadd --gid 2000 tripwire && \
useradd --system --uid 2000 --gid tripwire tripwire

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY scripts/daemon.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/utils
COPY scripts/mock.py /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/vne

USER root:root

ENTRYPOINT sleep infinity
```

Comment: You are using a multistage build. You create the folder in the first stage image. Only the last stage image in your multistage gets created as an image you can use on your local docker installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create the directory in the build stage of the build. That doesn't end up in the final image. Only things after the last FROM statement in the Dockerfile end up in the image.

So instead of

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect
COPY config/config.json /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect

##############################################################
FROM python:2.7.18-slim
```

You should do

```
##############################################################
FROM python:2.7.18-slim
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect
COPY config/config.json /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ip360da/data/connect
```